# Multiple sum variable notation

Tags: index-notation, gauss-sums

I have a question regarding multiple sum variables.
Is it correct to rewrite this sum like this ?

$$ \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}^{}\frac{i}{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\frac{i}{j} $$

and how do we rewrite sums like this in general ?

Comment: The upper index on the fist sum should be $n-1$ not $j-1$

Comment: doesn't it mean that $i$ loops from $1$ to $j-1$ ? and then we have $j$ from $i+1$ to $n$ ?

Answer (score 2):

It takes experience 
and I still make mistakes.
What helps is
trying small $n$
(1, 2, 3 are usually enough)
and seeing if
the sums are the same.

The outer sum
has to involve $n$,
since it is done first
and the inner sum
done for each value
in the inner sum.

The sum can be written
in (at least) two ways.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}^{}\frac{i}{j} 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\frac{i}{j}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{i}{j}\\
\end{array}
$

Since the inner sum is empty
for $i=n$ in the first sum
and
$j=1$ for the second sum,
they can also be written
like this.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}^{}\frac{i}{j} 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\frac{i}{j}\\
&= \sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{i}{j}\\
\end{array}
$

Since a sum is zero
when the lower bound
is greater than the upper bound,
the two ways are the same.

You can also pull out 
factors that
do not depend on
the inner index of summation,
so the sums could be written
like this.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}^{}\frac{i}{j} 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\frac{i}{j}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}i\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}\\
\text{and}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{i}{j}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{j}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

The second sum defines $j$ in terms of $i$.  You can't also have the first sum define $i$ in terms of $j$.  That would just take your round in a circle.

We sum over all pairs $(i,j)$ such that $1\leq i<j\leq n$  What values can $i$ take?  The smallest is $1$, obviously, and the largest is $n-1$, because $j$ can't be bigger than $n$ and $i$ must be less than $j$.  That accounts for the indices on the first sum.  You've already figured out how to write the indices on the second sum.

Comment: oh that makes sense, another thing I realized is say we have $ 1 \leq i < j \leq n $ , we can "cross j" for a moment(as it doesn't exist) what we are left with is $ 1 \leq i < n $ which means $i$ loops from $1$ to $n-1$.

Comment: @Noodle That works in this case, but if we have $1\leq i < j <k\leq n$ though, the biggest that $i$ can be is $n-2$.

Answer (score 1):

The argument in the sum can (and should) be ignored here. If you regard the coordinate $i$ as indicating the rows and $j$ the columns, of an $n\times n$ matrix $(a_{ij})$ then $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_{ij}$ is a finite sum over the matrix elements above the off-diagonal of the matrix (note, $j$ starts at $2$). Since the sum is finite, you can do it any way you want. Now, fix a column $j\ge 2$. Then, the sum of the elements in the $j^{\text{th}}$ column are those from the first to the $(j-1)^{\text{th}}$ row. That is, $\sum^{j-1}_{i=1}a_{ij}.$  Now, sum over all such columns. There are $n-1$ of them, and so you get $\sum^n_{j=2}\sum^{j-1}_{i=1}a_{ij}.$

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange it as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{i}{j}$ or $\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{i}{j}$; either way, you have an outer sum with an index whose limits are functions of $n$, and an inner sum with an index whose limits are functions of $n$ and the outer sum's index.